# Threading Selenium In Python

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to thread multiple instances of Chromedriver in selenium but everything I run by code, it seems to only open one instance of Chromdriver, although the thread is evidently working

This is the for loop which calls the threads:

```
for i in range (4):
    browserThread = threading.Thread(target=mainExtractor, args=(1000000, 50,2))
    browserThread.start()
```

I have a main function which does some initialization and calls another function called dataScraper(), both functions include a driver.get

```
def dataScraper(minimumComparisonCount=1, pageToStartOn=1, totalNumberPages=1, 
maxPropertyPrice=1):
print("Program going to start extracting from page: ", pageToStartOn)

#Loop through every page of the website, bounderies being what page to start on and the total pages
for currentPageExtractorIsOn in range(pageToStartOn, totalNumberPages):
    # Navigate to the webpage, given what page we will start to extract from, and the maximum price, and some other MISC entries, this is in a loop so it will keep going for every page
    bayutPropertiesLink = f"https://www.bayut.com/for-sale/property/dubai/page-{currentPageExtractorIsOn}/?price_max={maxPropertyPrice}&completion_status=ready"
    print(bayutPropertiesLink)
    #Load selenium into webpage
    driver.get(bayutPropertiesLink)

    #Get the HREF of each property, and store it in a list
    # Define a list to store the items
    propertiesHREFList = []

    propertyCards = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "_287661cb")

    # Loop through and extract the items from each card
    for property in propertyCards:
        propertyHref = property.get_attribute("href")
        propertiesHREFList.append(propertyHref)


    # Print the extracted items
    for item in propertiesHREFList:
        print(item)

    # Close the WebDriver
    #driver.quit()

def mainExtractor(maxPropertyPrice, minimumComparisonCount=1, pageToStartOn=1):
    # Define main URL
    mainUrl = f"https://www.bayut.com/for-sale/property/dubai/?price_max={maxPropertyPrice}&completion_status=ready"
driver.get(mainUrl)

#Gets number of pages, each page will show 24 items, we can see how many pages is by numofitems/24
totalNumberPages = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ca3976f7")

#Split by space and get fifth item which is total num of proerptes, round down/remove decimal places because we dont want to round up and make an extra non-existant page
totalNumberPages = math.floor((int(totalNumberPages.text.split(" ")[4].replace(",","")))/24)

#Other Initialization such as removes images from image save folder
imageSaveDirectory = r'D:\Programming Related\Property Investments Website\public\image\individualPropertyAnalysis'
# Use shutil.rmtree to delete the directory and its contents
if os.path.exists(imageSaveDirectory):
    shutil.rmtree(imageSaveDirectory)

#Make Mong Connections
mongoUri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/dbPropertyAnalysis"
# Create a new client and connect to the server
client = MongoClient(mongoUri, server_api=ServerApi('1'))
# Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
try:
    client.admin.command('ping')
    print("Connect to Mongo Database")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# Create or use a specific database
db = client["dbPropertyAnalysis"]

# Create or use a specific collection within the database
collection = db["items"]

#Delete All Previous Entries As We Are Extracting New Data
collection.delete_many({})


#Call and run the datascraper function within our main function
dataScraper(minimumComparisonCount, pageToStartOn, totalNumberPages, maxPropertyPrice)

mainExtractor(1000000, 50)

for i in range (4):
     browserThread = threading.Thread(target=mainExtractor, args=(1000000, 50,2))
     browserThread.start()
```

I've looked at some other Stack Overflow posts on this topic, but none seem to be facing my exact issue, so im wondering, how or why is my program not running multiple instances of chromedriver? Thanks.

Comment: can't see where you're initializing the driver, but that needs to be done in each thread.  (in "mainExtractor"?)

Comment: By initialize do you mean driver.get?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, this whole time i had my driver init outside the function, I put it in the main function and it worked.